# How to use visual studio features in Lightswitch

Tags: .net, visual-studio, reference, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm having trouble using visual studio features in Lightswitch. For example, add web reference is not available in the advanced tab of the add service reference option (the button is missing). And add service reference does not seem to work with all ebay API calls. Also, lightswitch doest allow me to use other visual studio functions like system.windows.forms.

I saw in a previous post that it is possible to work around this by creating a silverlight class library.

[Add refrence problem in silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912306/add-refrence-problem-in-silverlight/12255780#12255780)
However, I tried creating a silverlight class library but noticed that I still could not reference the usual .NET functions available in visual studio or call a web reference. Apart from clicking start new project-->create silverlight class library: what else do I need to do to make .NET functions work in the silverlight class library?

I'm very new to programming so I would appreciate some more help with this. 
Also, in the above link it is suggested that I create a link from withing lightswitch to an external program. Can someone please help me with understanding what is meant by this and what I need to do in visual studio to do this?

Been at this for a few days, appreciate your response.

Comment: I strongly suggest you go learn about LightSwitch before complaining about how it's not what you expected.

Comment: I have spent days reading my 3 books on lightswitch and browsing the net trying to learn about it. This post was not intended as a complaint at all and I have no expectations about what lightswitch can and cant do. Please dont impose unjustified assumptions on me

Comment: The assumptions seem fairly justified. You seem to be trying to do things "the Visual Studio way" instead of doing them the "LightSwitch way".

Comment: Ok whatever. How do I do it in Lightswitch please?

Comment: See, for example, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj618303.aspx, also [tag:lightswitch].

Comment: Also, I just found http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2012/09/04/lightswitch-in-visual-studio-2012-new-how-do-i-videos-released.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/. Finally, have you written any LightSwitch applications at all, or are you just starting?

Comment: John, your links are for VS 2012/LS V2, whereas I'm almost positive that John has V1.

Comment: @YannDuran: Exactly how different are they likely to be?

Comment: @Danny: perhaps I'm misunderstanding you. Are you trying to create a Visual Studio program, or a LightSwitch program?

Comment: @Danny - there's a major difference in look between VS 2010 & VS 2012, so my main concern was that you might be confused seeing screen shots that didn't match what you were seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your responses :) Yes I have VS 2010 and LS 1 (I think). But Im sure the links will be useful, especially if I get vs 2012 later.

Answer (score 2):

Danny, welcome to programming, & welcome to LightSwitch especially.

It sounds to me like you might have stand-alone LightSwitch. LightSwitch 2011 was released as a stand-alone product, which would either work on its own, or integrate into any existing version of VS 2010 Pro (or above). If that's the case, you only have access to Silverlight functionality in your code (unless you use the "trick" I mention below). For LS V2, they seem to have discontinued the stand-alone version & simply made it available in all versions of VS 2012 (Pro or above).

Even if you create a Silverlight project, as you've discovered, it won't allow you to use the full range of what's available in the .NET framework. Silverlight is a subset of the fulll .NET framework, which was created mainly for web applications (although OOB, or Out Of Browser functionality was added later).

There is a way we've been getting around the restriction, that we've come to call the "Command Table Pattern" (though it's not really an official pattern). This article explains how it works: [Being Serious About The Command Table Pattern](http://blog.pragmaswitch.com/?p=332)

Beth Massi's [How Do I Videos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/lightswitch/ff945359) are an excellent resource for people new to LightSwitch, but a lot of her content has been updated to LS V2 (VS 2012). The offical LightSwitch forum, [Visual Studio LightSwitch - General Questions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/threads), is also a good place to ask questions (even newbie ones).

For any serious programming, that would need the full .NET framework, it was intended that you'd need Visual Studio Professional (or above).

I don't know which 3 books you've read, but in the one that I co-authored with Tim Leung, should have covered your initial question.

I hope I've helped you understand a bit better why you haven't been able to do what you thought you could.

Comment: As a comment, John doesn't have the power to delete answers, as he's not a moderator. Your original answer was flagged for the unnecessary personal commentary, and a moderator decided to remove the entire thing as a result. We might have been a little hasty with that, so I've just edited out the side comments from your new answer to leave behind just your useful technical content. If you feel someone is being rude in comments, it's fine to correct them there or flag those comments, but we prefer to keep questions and answers on topic.

Comment: Thanks for your response Yann. Yes I have your book on Kindle! I'm surprised and grateful to get such a professional response. And thanks also for telling me about the lightswitch forum :)